# Can I SELECT from mysql 5 values from top N(10)? (rand)

Tags: php, mysql

I need take from MYSQL 5 values that taked from top 10 values randomly?

**Exmple:**
I'v 100  posts in my db and I want take 5 of them that have views number in top 10 posts. How can I do it by only one command in mysql?

Comment: Select top ten and then reduce array to 5 elements.

Comment: MySQL doesnt support TOP @MilanChheda.. you are mixing MySQL with sql-server

Comment: Oops. Apologies. My mistake. I will delete it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM 
(SELECT * FROM posts order by id DESC limit 0,10) as p1 
ORDER BY rand() limit 0,5
```

Please change fields according your database structure

Comment: `Limit 5` is enough.